# PHP script from Guestbook doesn't add to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

When I submit guestbook details via php form, it ends with "Successful", but when I look at MySQL database, it just creates new entry, but no details are present expect the automatic ID and date.

Here's the form: guestbook.php

```
 <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="addguestbook.php">
 <td><input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="40" /></td>
 <td><input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="40" /></td>
 <td><textarea name="comment" cols="40" rows="3" id="comment"></textarea></td>
 <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" 
 name="Submit2" value="Reset" /></td>
```

Here's the script: addguestbook.php

```
 $host="address"; // Host name 
 $username="username"; // Mysql username 
 $password="password"; // Mysql password 
 $db_name="guestdb"; // Database name 
 $tbl_name="guestbook"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select database.
 mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect server "); 
 mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

 $datetime=date("y-m-d h:i:s"); //date time

 $sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(name, email, comment, datetime)VALUES('$name', '$email',     
'$comment', '$datetime')";
 $result=mysql_query($sql);

//check if query successful 
 if($result){
 echo "Successful";
 echo "<BR>";

// link to view guestbook page
 echo "<a href='viewguestbook.php'>View guestbook</a>";}

 else {
 echo "ERROR";}
 mysql_close();
```

Comment: Where do you define `$name`, `$email`, and `$comment`? And you should look at using PDO or mysqli, as this will likely have an SQL injection vulnerability otherwise.

Comment: You have not populated the `$name` or `$comment`, or `$email`  variables.

Comment: `var_dump($sql)` - Have a look at what you're actually trying to do. Debug! Likely this code expects `register_globals` to be on, which is a terrible idea.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Also please start with debugging. Enable error reporting to the highest level so that you actually take notice about potential problems, PHP will tell you about them: `error_reporting(~0); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` or even better configure that in your php.ini.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That I can see, you havn't defined your variables.. Add this above `$datetime=da...`.

```
$name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : false;
$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : false;
$comment = isset($_POST['comment']) ? $_POST['comment'] : false;
```

In addition to this:

- Please use [mysqli_*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) queries or PDO
- Use mysql*_real_escape_string to [create a legal SQL string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

Answer (score 4):

Before prepare sql query (`$sql`), you must populate `$name`, `$email` and `$comment` vars with `$_POST` data.

```
<?php

// ..

$name    = $_POST['name'];
$email   = $_POST['email'];
$comment = $_POST['comment'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO $tbl_name(name, email, comment, datetime)VALUES('$name', '$email',     
'$comment', '$datetime')";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

// ..
```

**Bonus:** Use [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Answer (score 1):

There could be multiple reasons for this.

I would suggest changing your query to this:

```
INSERT INTO $tbl_name set name='$name', email='$email', comment='$comment', datetime='$datetime'
```